# Add Corner Radius and drop shadow to UICollectionViewCell Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, dropshadow, cornerradius

I'm trying to add **corner radius + dropdown shadow** to my UICollectionView Cell,

my Cell sturcuture is like this:

[image]

I added view to add shadow on it, and try to add corner radius to the to subviews: the white one and the imageview, I used the following code:

```
        let frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 80)

    shadowingViewOutlet.layer.masksToBounds = false
    shadowingViewOutlet.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shadowingViewOutlet.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(0.0), height: CGFloat(3.0))
    shadowingViewOutlet.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5

    if shadowingViewOutlet.layer.shadowPath != nil {


        shadowingViewOutlet.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:frame, cornerRadius:3).cgPath
    }
```

but that dosen't work fine!

Anyone try to apply the same functionlaity to **UICollectionViewCell** and have a result in it?

please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Answer: stop using Swift, then in Objective-C subclass a cell then add corner radius and drop shadow to the subclass

Comment: @Loxx is there a helpful external classes can help me even if it's in objective-C? for sure I CANT stop using swift! it's my job

Comment: You can use this class https://github.com/benboecker/ShadowView/blob/master/ShadowView/ShadowView.swift

Comment: @BurakÖztürk Thanks for answer